# Strange behavior of socket outputstream android

Tags: java, android

I wrote an `android` app which connect to `ServerSocket` (that written in `Java`) and supposed to transfer some data in parallel.
I have 3 socket - one for text transfer and two for data transfer(sound, images etc..)
everything works fine in the first hours, but after that the `write()` method get stuck and doesn't transfer any data, and after about 15 minutes I get `sendto failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)` exception.
The strange thing is that the text do get transferred anytime..
I am using `DataOutputStream` to transfer the text and `BufferedOutputStrem` to transfer the data..
The base code is simple:

```
    while((max=fis.read(b))!=-1){
       dataOut.write(b, 0, max);
       dataOut.flush();
    }
   fis.close();
```

and in the server:

```
while(counter<size){        
    max = dataStream.read(b);
    fos.write(b, 0, max);
    counter = counter + max;
}
fos.close();
```

**Edit:
Ok I finally found out the problem..
It looks like that socket which not send some data for a long time will not work properly.
so I will have to send one byte every X minutes..**

Comment: Don't put `flush()` calls inside loops; don't use multiple streams on the same socket, and don't use `PrintWriter` or `PrintStream` over a network, as they swallow exceptions you need to know about as soon as they happen. However 'connection timed out' on a write indicates a fatal connection failure: there's nothing you can do from this end except close the socket and maybe retry the whole thing.

Comment: I am not using multiple streams on the same socket every client has 3 sockets which running on like separate threads.. I just don't understand why the sockets which transfer the data get stuck at write method after the phone sleep about a hour but the socket which transfer text works fine