# Java on Android - Strange socket behavior with InputStream timeout errors

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, android-networking

I have an app which uses an instance of the `Socket` class to communicate with a server.
I use the streams returned by `socket.getInputStream()` and `socket.getOutputStream()` to read and write data.

When my Android app is always "active" (not minimized), there is no problem with the communication. It does not matter how long the connection lasts.

When I "pause" the application and re-open it quickly, everything still works fine.
However, when I pause the application for about 5 minutes and re-open it, the `InputStream` shows strange behavior: it stops reading anything. I get timeout errors instead of the data sent by the server.

The connection is still alive, the server is able to write and read. `isInputShutdown()` on the client-side returns false.

Using a network analysis tool, I can also see that the data sent by the server IN FACT reaches the client but it somehow does not get recognized by the `InputStream` ...

However, writing data from the client to the server using the `OutputStream` works fine.

Maybe it's worth mentioning that the socket object and the streams are declared as `static` to be accessible for all the activities of the app. But as I don't have any problems with the `OutputStream`, I cannot imagine that this could be the reason.

The only workaround I have at this point is to close the whole socket and connect a new one to the server. But this is causing unnecessary network traffic because I have to handshake again. It would be better not to do it this way.

If anyone has had similar experience and found a solution, I would be really happy if you could share it with me.

Comment: This is reminiscent of bizarre behaviors I've seen, not from `java.io.Socket` (yet... knock wood!) but from `android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket`.  These kinds of behaviors tend to be specific to a particular device, carrier, OS update, and/or SDK version.  Exactly what environment are you seeing this in?

Comment: See this "related" question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212395/strange-behavior-of-socket-outputstream-android?rq=1

Comment: I was experiencing this problem on a htc wildfire - android 2.3.7. Thanks to you, but I just tried the same thing on multiple devices and it seems to be not device or SDK related.

Thanks to the "related" question. It is really weird that this person points out that sockets stop working if you dont send data every x minutes. But I am going to try this

Comment: `isInputShutdown()` is irrelevant. It doesn't tell you anything about the state of the connection, only whether you have called `shutdownInput()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kevin Krumwiede pointed out by referring to this post: [Strange behavior of socket outputstream android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212395/strange-behavior-of-socket-outputstream-android?rq=1), when sending data every X minutes (e.g. 3 or 4), everything still works as it should even after 30 minutes of being 'paused'.

I had the hope that `Socket.setKeepAlive(true)` would be enough to keep the connection alive so I dont have to cause too much unnecessary network traffic but in my particular case, this does not help.

Sending 1 byte of 'garbage' every X minutes 'solves' the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a service that will be run in background and implement socket connection with a server.